# Efficient search of unique owners of files and directories

Tags: files, ls, recursive

I would like to view the unique owners of all the files and directories underneath a certain directory.

I have tried:

```
ls -ltR <dir-path> | grep -P '^[d|\-]' | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq
```

Which commits the cardinal sin of trying to parse `ls` output, but works -- until I try it on a directory with an immense amount of files within a complex directory structure where it bogs down and hangs.

While I could work around and simply do the command at lower levels and work up piece by piece, I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a slightly shorter version that uses find:

`find <path> -printf "%u\n" | sort -u`

Depending on the complexity of the directory structure, this may or may not be more efficient.

Comment: In this case (i.e. assuming number of files is large, number of users is small), `gawk '1{u[$0]=1;} END{ for (x in u){print x;}}'` might be better than `sort -u` since it doesn't store one line per file.

Comment: Good point. I think uniq -u does essentially the same thing, I've updated my response.

Comment: @don_crissti You're right -- sloppy reading of the man page on my part. I've changed my answer back to sort -u. Ulrich's answer will be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

For this sort of task, I like to break out the perl. There's a module called `File::Find` which is core, that is quite good for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my %found;

sub collate_users {
    next if -d;
    my ($dev,  $ino,   $mode,  $nlink, $uid,     $gid, $rdev,
        $size, $atime, $mtime, $ctime, $blksize, $blocks
    ) = stat;

    if ( not $found{$uid} ) {
        print "$uid : ", getpwuid($uid),"\n";
    }
    $found{$uid}++;
}

find( \&collate_users, "/path/to/search", "/another/path/to/search" );
```

This'll print in 'found order' - you could if you prefer, collate and sort (by count of files if you're so inclined) later:

```
foreach my $uid ( sort { $found{$a} <=> $found{$b} } keys %found ) {
    print getpwbyuid($uid)," ($uid) has $found{$uid} files\n";
}
```